# Find Constant Regions in Pandas Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have the following Pandas series

```
s = pd.series([1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2])

i | val
----
0 | 1
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 2
4 | 2
5 | 3
6 | 3
7 | 2
8 | 2
```

Id like to find the regions where values are the same. So the result might be something like this:

```
# list of [value, [range]] pairs
[[1,[0,3]], [2,[3,5]], [3,[5,7]], [2,[7,9]]]
```

Another similar representation would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try use `diff` with `cumsum` get the `groupby` key , then `groupby` with `agg`

```
l = s.reset_index().groupby(s.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).agg({0:'first','index':lambda x : [x.min(),x.max()]}).values.tolist()
l
Out[35]: [[1, [0, 2]], [2, [3, 4]], [3, [5, 6]], [2, [7, 8]]]
```

Comment: It seems like the preceding value is the group number, not the value of the group. It seems trivial to index the list to get the value of the group, but is there an elegant way to make that output [1,[]],[2,[]],[3,[]],[2,[]] (i.e. that final 4, instead of being the group number, is instead the value of the group 2)?